# How to obtain "Proof of theorem [number of the theorem] " using elsarticle

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, elsarticle

I am using the `elsarticle` document class. I want to find a way to add the number in the proof environment to obtain something like this:

> Proof of theorem 2.

Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us how you defined the theorem-like environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `elsarticle`:

> users are free to make use of ams math packages such as `amsmath.sty`, `amsthm.sty`, `amssymb.sty`, `amsfonts.sty`, etc., if they want to.

The class provides `\newproof` for defining proof environments, but the implementation is not as good as in `amsthm`, so my advice is to load it and use

```
\begin{proof}
...
\end{proof}
```

If you want a different title, do

```
\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem \ref{...}]
...
\end{proof}
```

Replace the dots in `\ref{...}` with the appropriate label.